# Articles in front of uncountable nouns

Tags: grammaticality

Can we use an indefinite article before an uncountable noun if it is followed by an adjective?

For example:

> I gain a useful information every time I browse the site. We need a strong evidence to believe him as he lied to us many times. He gave me a useful advice.

Comment: Not in these three cases, but I'm curious to see what you've discovered about this topic so far.

Comment: We can, but only under restricted conditions. Your examples do not qualify. Generally, an adjective is present, but not always: "He wastes a great _deal_ of time"; "I have a high _regard_ for him"; Kim has a good _knowledge_ of Greek"; "A _number_ of problems remain".

Comment: It's "a useful PIECE of information/advice/evidence" or  "We need **a** lot of evidence"

Comment: You can also use quantifiers. While not indefinite articles, they are used in a similar way : *I gain* ***more*** *useful information*, *I gain* ***some*** useful information*, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

No, that's exactly wrong. No article is used in English when there is no quantity or physical object. The house, a house, houses. I want a cow. I want the cow. I want cows.

I need a lot of information.

I need useful information.

I need a vital piece of information [referencing a specific amount or object].

We need strong evidence.

We need more evidence.

We need an important piece of evidence.

We need the last piece of evidence.